# R: Helper function that checks arguments within an environment

Tags: r, validation, arguments, user-defined-functions

In R (3.4.3),

I'm trying to make my code more succinct before I move it to a package. I'm struggling to find a simple way to check actual arguments passed to multiple functions within an environment, especially when some of those arguments have default values. My goal is not paste redundant code in each of the functions, maintaining readability, and not running into scoping issues. Here is an example (imagine these functions being within the same environment/script):

**Current Code**

```
foo_add <- function(x, y = x, divisible = TRUE) {

 if(missing(x) || !is.numeric(x)) stop("define x as a number")
 if(!is.numeric(y)) y <- x
 if(!is.logical(divisible)) stop("define divisible as TRUE or FALSE")

 ...}


foo_subtract <- function(x, y = x, divisible = TRUE) {

 if(missing(x) || !is.numeric(x)) stop("define x as a number")
 if(!is.numeric(y)) y <- x
 if(!is.logical(divisible)) stop("define divisible as TRUE or FALSE")

 ...}


foo_divide <- function(x, y = x, divisible = TRUE) {

 if(missing(x) || !is.numeric(x)) stop("define x as a number")
 if(!is.numeric(y)) y <- x
 if(!is.logical(divisible)) stop("define divisible as TRUE or FALSE")

 ...}
```

You can see that I'm repeating code just to verify the useR defined the arguments correctly. Below I've added a list return just to check if things worked. My rendition of a cleaner version:

**Desired Code**

```
foo_add <- function(x, y = x, divisible = TRUE) {
     do.call("check_args", mget(names(formals())))
     list(x,y,divisible)
   }


foo_subtract <- function(x, y = x, divisible = TRUE) {
     do.call("check_args", mget(names(formals())))
     list(x,y,divisible)
   }


foo_divide <- function(x, y = x, divisible = TRUE) {
     do.call("check_args", mget(names(formals())))
     list(x,y,divisible)
   }

check_args <- function(x,y,divisible) {
     if(missing(x) || !is.numeric(x)) stop("define x as a number")
     if(!is.numeric(y)) y <- x
     if(!is.logical(divisible)) stop("define divisible as TRUE or FALSE")
   }
```

Basically what I want to do is always check if actual arguments are specified correctly while controlling for default arguments and missing arguments. From my basic knowledge I kind of want to make a constructor-esk function for actual arguments. I also want to have the ability of not only error-checking but modifying actual argument values and returning them to the parent function for use (e.g., like the condition `if(!is.numeric(y)) y <- x`).

The Desired Code seems to work, I just want to make sure, given how new I am to R programming, that I'm accounting for things. Specifically if I modify objects within the `check_args()` then pass them to a parent function using `do.call`. *Is there a cleaner way to go about doing this?*

**Updated Solution** I've created a, somewhat extensible, solution  [see here](https://github.com/Shea-Fyffe/GitItSheaGitIt/blob/master/R/argument_validator_functions.R)